# How do I store an access token so it is available across tabs?

Tags: token

So I have created an API that returns a JSON payload containing an access token after logging in. On all subsequent requests, I want the token to be sent back to the server. That's the easy part.

The part that's tripping me up is where to store the token. I was thinking sessionStorage, but that's only available in one tab. Then I thought localStorage, but I don't like how long it persists.

I guess I'm wondering if there is a third option.

Answer (score 1):

cookie: you can set an expiration